# Joomla component include JavaScript, pop error

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3.0, joomla-component, pttimeselect

I'm new in Joomla, I have try to build my Joomla component, however, when I try to include Jquery ptTimeSelect library into front end it shows javascript error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_doCheckMouseClick' of undefined

I did a lot google, and did change the place of the code, it seems Joomla automatic ignore part of the code cause this problem（maybe it skipping any code with "_"underscore ), and I did try to rename _doCheckMouseClick to doCheckMouseClick, it show the same kind error message.

here are the code pops error

calling function: line 228 in file

```
 $(document).mousedown(jQuery.ptTimeSelect._doCheckMouseClick);
```

define function: line 387 in file

```
 /**
 * Closes the timePicker popup if user is not longer focused on the
 * input field or the timepicker
 * 
 * @private
 * @param {jQueryEvent} ev -    Event passed in by jQuery
 * @return {undefined}
 */
jQuery.ptTimeSelect._doCheckMouseClick = function(ev){
    if (!$("#ptTimeSelectCntr:visible").length) {
        return;
    }
    if (   !jQuery(ev.target).closest("#ptTimeSelectCntr").length
        && jQuery(ev.target).not("input.isPtTimeSelectActive").length ){
        jQuery.ptTimeSelect.closeCntr();
    }

};// jQuery.ptTimeSelect._doCheckMouseClick
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the real code.. But sometimes this problem from jquery version. Perhaps u must use **jquery no conflict**

Answer (score 0):

After few try, I found out Joomla have a bug with include JavaScript library, and I solve this problem by copy the code directly into the view/default template, by using

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration("
  //300 lines of ptTimeSelect code
")
```

Hope this help for others who meet the same problem.